# How to include only selective packages in SSIS manifest file for deployment?

Tags: deployment, ssis, manifest

I have recently started to build manifest files for the ETL packages by navigating to the project properties and setting the Create Deployment Utility to true. I was using batch files before this to deploy the packages, but can't run them anymore because I don't have enough permissions on the server after a new system roll-out.

The problem is that in some cases, I only need to deploy a couple of ETL packages instead of all of the packages under the project. When the project is built, the manifest file lists all the packages under the project that may or may not be required for deployment.

Is there any way for me to only include a couple of ETL packages in the manifest file instead of every package under the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MSDN, the possible option seems to be adding the necessary packages that should be deployed to a different SSIS project and use the deployment utility on that project.

[*Redeployment of Packages*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141124.aspx)

#### Quote from MSDN:

After you finish updating the packages, you rebuild the project, copy the deployment folder to the target computer, and then rerun the Package Installation Wizard.

If you update only a few packages in the project, you may not want to redeploy the entire project. To deploy only a few packages, you can create a new Integration Services project, add the updated packages to the new project, and then build and deploy the project. Package configurations are automatically copied with the package when you add the package to a different project.

Comment: That's what I thought too but wanted to check if someone had a solution for this. Thanks